# TreadFactory set time-based priority

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Currently, I am using a **custom task executor** to execute some methods in a SpringBoot application. It uses a `custom thread factory` to create low priority threads for the executor as follows :

thread factory :

```java
public final class JobThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private int priority;
    private boolean daemon;
    private final String namePrefix;
    private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public JobThreadFactory(int priority) {
        this(priority, true);
    }

    public OpJobThreadFactory(int priority, boolean daemon) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.daemon = daemon;
        namePrefix = "jobpool-" +poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-thread-";
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement());
        t.setDaemon(daemon);
        t.setPriority(priority);
        return t;
    }
}
```

in custom thread executor bean :

```java
executor.setThreadFactory(new jobThreadFactory(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-2));//set priority here
```

Now I have a requirement to create threads in a way that, they have time-based thread priority. eg :

```
t = 0(when thread is starting(not creating)) : priority = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY -1
t = 500ms : priority = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY -2
```

**All threads should be started at (normal priority-1) then, reduced to normal priority-2) after 500ms.**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps two threads are created - A and B, where B knows about A. A sleeps for 500 ms, and when it wakes up adjust the priority of A and B ends.  It will be at least 500 ms, but not exactly 500 ms.

Comment: This creates like 60 threads per minute. So, your idea will be inefficient.

Comment: What is the nature of the work the thread is doing?  Could you add checkpoints to see how much time has passed since the thread started, to allow the thread to manage its own priority?